# Creating excel grid like image for an iPhone application- what UI element should I use?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I am trying to build out an excel like grid for an iPhone application. It will be ten by ten making a total of 100 boxes.  Does anyone have any advice/tutorials on how to arrange this in the xib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a great project on github for this: https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController